# Writing MySql Where clause inside php foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

How to write mysql where clause inside php foreach loop. here is my code

```
$outPut = Array ( [0] => 'intel' [1] => 'amd' );
$Query = select * from laptop
foreach($outPut as $Filtervalues)
{
  $Query .= "where processor like '%$Filtervalues%'";
}

echo $Query;
```

But my output is not correct.

i want output to be as

```
select * from laptop where (processor like '%intel%' or processor like '%amd%')
```

Comment: what are you currently getting

Comment: @Armand i am getting out put as `select * from laptop where processor like '%intel%' where processor like '%amd%'`

Comment: @All: variables in php are case sensitive `$outPut` differs from `$output` I guess that's another mistake.

Comment: try mine answer :) should work: http://codepad.org/bMrilK67

Comment: @All: his array initialization is wrong, too.

Comment: in php [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) should be lowercase `array()` not `Array()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the `WHERE` clause only for the first filter parameter:

```
$output = Array ( 'intel', 'amd' );
$Query = select * from laptop
$firsttime=true;

foreach($output as $Filtervalues)
{
    if($firsttime){
        $Query .= "where";
        $firsttime=false;
    }
    else
        $Query .= "or";

    $Query .= " processor like '%Filtervalues%' ";
}

echo $Query;
```

Answer (score 4):

foreach not needed:

```
<?
$output = Array ( 'intel', 'amd' );
$Query = echo 'select * from laptop where processor LIKE \'%'.join($output,'%\' OR processor LIKE \'%').'\'%';
?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: if you use quotes properly you can avoid the backslashes and make code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$counter = 0;
$output = Array ( [0] => 'intel' [1] => 'amd' );
$Query = "select * from laptop ";
if(count($output) > 0)
     $Query .= " where ( ";
foreach($outPut as $Filtervalues)
{
    $counter++;
    $Query .= "processor like '%$Filtervalues%'";
    if($counter != count($output))
        $Query .= " or ";
    else
        $Query .= ")";
}

echo $Query;
```

Comment: That will produce several `where`! Only 1 `where` should be added before the loop, in case `$Filtervalues` is not empty

Comment: parse erreor in line 3 :)

Comment: That will result to error if there's no $filterValues. The where should be added only if $filterValues has a count more than 0

Comment: @Nadeem_MK you mean `$output`.

Comment: @Christoph Yeah sorry ;)

Comment: the output of the above code is like `select * from laptop where ( processor like '%intel%' )processor like '%amd%' or`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?php 

$output = Array ( 'intel' , 'amd' );
$Query = 'select * from laptop where ';
foreach($output as $Filtervalues)
{
  $whereQuery .= "processor like '%".$Filtervalues."%' OR ";
}

echo $Query . substr($whereQuery, 0, -3);


?>
```

[WORKING CODE](http://codepad.org/bMrilK67)

Comment: That will result to error if there's no `$filterValues`. The where should be added only if $filterValues has a count more than 0

Comment: @Nadeem_MK $output = Array ( [0] => 'intel' [1] => 'amd' ); 
count($output) = 2    -> NOT 0

Comment: @Adam ok, but you can't assume it will remain this way. If `$output`was to remain fixed, OP could as well hard code his query.

Answer (score 1):

You could add all conditions to an array and just join its elements later.

```
$output = array ( 'intel', 'amd' );
$Query = 'select * from laptop';
$likes = array();
foreach($output as $Filtervalues)
{
  $likes[] = "processor like '%$Filtervalues%'";
}
if(!empty($likes))
    $Query .= ' where ('.implode(' or ', $likes) . ')';
echo $Query;
```

Comment: @Christoph: Thanks for the edit. I prematurely submitted and was doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$output = Array ( 'intel', 'amd' );
$Query = "select * from laptop ";

if(count($output)>0){
    $Query .= "WHERE";

    foreach($output as $Filtervalues){
        $Query .= " processor like '%$Filtervalues%' OR";
    }
    $Query = trim($Query, " OR");
}

echo $Query;
```